# Animating td's using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate the opacity of td's using jquery. When one td is clicked upon I want to animate any td's out and fade in the td that's been clicked on.

I'm getting a strange problem with flickering:

http://jsfiddle.net/s4gtp/

The td being clicked on fades in but then quickly fades in and out again. I've checked firebug and the event is only being fired once. I've tried the same code with an un-ordered list and everything works as expected.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: your Jsfiddle works as expected on both chrome and IE for me

Comment: I can't really help, but I do know that animating tables, and table cells is a *nightmare*. If you can I'd change this to use divs or a list, it'll be easier in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding in `.not($(this))` to the first animation:

```
$('tr td').click(function() {
    var i = $(this).index();
    $('tr td').not($(this)).animate({'opacity': '0.1'});
    $('tr td.item' + i).animate({'opacity': "1"});
});
```

Also, you need to specify `border-collapse:separate;` in your CSS for the table. This will resolve the issue you have in Firefox:

Here's an updated jsFiddle for you > http://jsfiddle.net/s4gtp/4/

As the other commenters have stated though, I didn't see any 'flickering', so I assume you mean that the clicked element fades out, and then fades back in...

Comment: Tried it with that and also the :not selector, it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: It seems that this is a Firefox specific problem - the updated fiddle is still doing the same thing for me

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean now. Just checked with Firefox on my MBP and now I see the problem. You can use the `border-collapse` property to resolve the issue. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: that's great. How did you find that solution?